# How do you clone a trace repository?

Tags: svn, vaadin, trace

How do you clone [this](https://dev.vaadin.com/browser/incubator/LazyLoadWrapper) repository? I can't find the url. Itried

```
svn checkout svn://dev.vaadin.com/browser/incubator/LazyLoadWrapper
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command:

svn checkout https://dev.vaadin.com/svn/incubator/LazyLoadWrapper/